# How to load font files in bundles using webpack, Angular 1.4.8 and Typescript?

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, html-webpack-plugin

I am not able to load font file (eot,svg,ttf,woff) and images (jpeg,png) in auto generated bundle folder using webpack, tried with below code options:

```
{
test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
}
{
test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
}
```

@font-face {
    font-family: 'GRM-Action-Icons';
    src: url(twbs-font-path('/fonts/xyz.eot')),url(twbs-font-path('/fonts/xyz.ttf')),url(twbs-font-path('/fonts/xyz.woff')),url(twbs-font-path('/fonts/xyz.svg'));
}

Comment: Try removing the `include` to check if the issue is not related to incorrect path resolution.

Comment: Thanks Nerve, i have tried removed include, but no luck its not working. here_dirname points to dist folder which is auto generated by webpack